# How to prevent moving of a UITableViewCell to a specific index

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application, the user has the ability to move `UITableViewCell` rows around using the edit button and drag and drop.

I do not want the user to be able to move a cell to row 0. I already have this working for my `NSMutableArray` where if the row is 0 then don't rearrange the objects in collection. But even with that in place, the visible table still shows the cell at row 0.

How can I prevent this graphically?

I've tried the following:

```
-(NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
        if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

But it crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I try to move cell at row 1 to row 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The problem is that `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath` method should return `NSIndexPath*`, but you return an integer. The fix is simple:

```
if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
{
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version

```
if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0){
return IndexPath.init(row: 1, section: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section)}
```